# How to write a script to fetch the address of the links to .rar files on a webpage?

Tags: shell, download, aria2

Have a pile of 50 .rar files on a web server and I want to download them all.
And, the names of the files have nothing in common other than .rar.

I wanted to try aria2 to download all of them altogether, but I think I need to write a script to fetch the addresses of all the .rar files.

I have no idea how to start writing the scrip. Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to play with wget with -A parameter in your shell script:

```
wget -r "https://foo/" -P /tmp -A "*.rar"
```

Here is an explanation of what -A does

> Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to accept or reject (see Types of Files). Note that if any of the wildcard characters, ‘*’, ‘?’, ‘[’ or ‘]’, appear in an element of acclist or rejlist, it will be treated as a pattern, rather than a suffix. In this case, you have to enclose the pattern into quotes to prevent your shell from expanding it, like in ‘-A "*.mp3"’ or ‘-A '*.mp3'’.